# Prove that if $A$ is nonsingular, then the sequence $X_{k+1}=X_k+X_k(I-AX_k)$ converges to $A^{-1}$ if and only if $ρ(I-X_0A)<1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove that if $A$ is nonsingular, then the sequence $X_{k+1}=X_k+X_k(I-AX_k)$ where $A$ and $X_k$ are $n\times n$ matrices with $k=0,1,2,...$ converges to $A^{-1}$ if and only if $ρ(I-X_0A)<1$.

I'm really stuck on this problem. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since January 20 all but one of the questions you have posted have lacked context. Several of your posts have been closed for this reason, yet you continue to ignore all warnings that the posting of questions without any explanation of your own thoughts or effort to solve them is not allowed on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $Y_k = I - A X_k$, you can write this as 
$Y_{k+1} = Y_k^2$, with $Y_0 = I - A X_0$.  Thus $Y_k = Y_0^{2^k}$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure I understand this though. What does this mean? Is this for the forward direction of the biconditional statement?

Comment: It's for both directions.  $Y_k \to 0$ if and only if $X_k \to A^{-1}$.  So now you want to show that $Y_0^{2^k} \to 0$ if and only if $\rho(Y_0) < 1$.